# Unable to login site Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do log in into my university site but i receive this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"}
```

this is the code part:

```
textboxes3 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")
textboxes3.click()
textboxes3.send_keys(matricola)
```

and this is the site inspection:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71sqb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try targeting the element by id:

```
textboxes3 = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
textboxes3.click()
textboxes3.send_keys(matricola)
```

Comment: i have the same error: ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)```

Comment: @GiulioMortillaro Is it a public page? Can you link the page please, so I can test on my side?

Answer (score 0):

Using browser.find_element_by_id("username") should work, but since it's still not finding the element then I suspect one of two issues might be occurring:

1. The element hasn't loaded yet and selenium needs to wait longer. I recommend using the WebDriverWait class to wait for the element to load.
2. Websites are divided into iframes, Selenium may be searching for the element in the wrong iframe. If this is the case you will need to use the driver.switch_to.frame function.

I recommend trying this code out first:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


w = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
textboxes3 = w.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
textboxes3.click()
textboxes3.send_keys('matricola')
```